# when I login to my foo user I will not be in my home directory?but when I login with other user like foo2 and then I su to the foo all things good

Tags: linux

when I login to my foo user I will not be in my home directory

```
foo@server's password:
Last login: Thu Nov 22 10:55:57 2012 from node1
-bash-4.1$ cd ~
-bash-4.1$ cd ~
```

but when I login with other user like foo2 and then I su to the foo user I will be in my home directory

I check the permission too and all things look fine :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to check what home directory is assigned to which user/login from /etc/passwd file.  If that is all fine, check for permissions for home directory of that user.  Change user's home directory permissions to 755 and then try.